# ActiveRecord not saving after updating attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I'm wondering if there is something at work here that I don't understand or if I've run into a bug in ActiveRecord (4.1.1).

I have a database full of records with only one attribute, a field a bit of JSON in it. I take one and try to update it like so.

```
test = Submission.find(1)
test.update_attribute('json_data',similar_but_different_json(test.json_data))
```

Let's assume the method `similar_but_different_json` makes a small update to that JSON. In my case I'm fixing some data errors that were created by a broken form.

When doing this, I don't get any errors, I show a commit in the console but no data submitted and get a return of `true`.

In order to actually update the record I have to do this.

```
test = Submission.find(1)
old_json_data = test.json_data
test.json_data = ""
test.json_data = similar_but_different_json(old_json_data)
test.save
```

What seems to be happening is that ActiveRecord doesn't identify that a change has been made that has to be saved. Could this be why setting the field to an empty string then back to JSON allows the record to save?

Comment: I should also mention that this isn't a full implementation of Rails. I'm using ActiveRecord with Sinatra.

Comment: I thought `update_attribute` was deprecated, in favour of `update_attributes`?

Comment: It is deprecated, but the issue also happens with `update_attributes`.

Comment: I opened an issue on the Rails repo to see if it's a bit in arecord. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15146

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958538/rails-is-not-saving-an-attribute-that-is-changed/29958539#29958539

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### `will_change!`

You can also use:

```
test.json_data_will_change!   # Goes before the save.
```

This will tell ActiveModel that the attribute, `json_data`, has changed (i.e. it's *dirty* ← there's a joke there somewhere) and will update the value properly on save.

See [Rails is not saving an attribute that is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958538/rails-is-not-saving-an-attribute-that-is-changed/29958539#29958539) for some more details as well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why exactly the object is not marked dirty. A workaround is to use `update_columns`:

```
test.update_columns(json_data: similar_but_different_json(test.json_data))
```

It will execute an UPDATE query directly in the DB, without any validation, dirty check, etc... The `json_data` field must not be read-only though.

Comment: That solution does indeed work. It's one line instead of the solution I tried first where I change the field to an empty string then back to JSON. I wasn't familiar with the 'dirty check' but it makes sense. I wonder if I should open an issue on the Rails Github repo.

Answer (score 2):

**ActiveModel (by 4.1.1) doesn't have a way to track "inline" modifications on attributes.**

Your 'similar_but_different_json' method is probably making inline modifications on the string.

Just duplicate the string before modifying it.

```
test = Submission.find(1)
test_json_data_duplicate = test.json_data.dup 
test.update_attribute('json_data',similar_but_different_json(test_json_data_duplicate))
```

When you did ...

```
test.json_data = ""
```

... ActiveModel could catch the change because you are setting it to a new String object that happens to be empty. So when you call update_attribute the model has already known that the attribute has changed.

If you try to empty the string in an inline manner your trick will not work.

```
test = Submission.find(1)
old_json_data = test.json_data
test.json_data.clear # Instead of test.json_data = ""
test.json_data = similar_but_different_json(old_json_data)
test.save
```

[ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)

Comment: Looks like this is being fixed in 4.2. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html