# Rails is not saving an attribute that is changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, attributes, dirty-data

I am appending some text to a `notes` field on one of my `ActiveRecord::Base` models but when I save it, it doesn't get updated:

```ruby
valve.notes                          
#=> "Level: Top"

valve.notes << "\nDirection: North"

valve.notes                          
#=> "Level: Top\nDirection: North"

valve.save                           
#=> true

valve.reload.notes                   
#=> "Level: Top"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Concat doesn't tell ActiveRecord that an Attribute has changed.

Figured it out and wanted to share it here for others (and most likely myself!) in the future.

I didn't know this but ActiveRecord cannot determine that an attribute has been changed (i.e. is *dirty*) when you concatenate it, either with `concat()` or `<<`. And because ActiveRecord only saves, or updates, attributes that have changed (i.e. are *dirty*), it doesn't update that attribute.

It's a sneaky little gotcha if you're not already aware of it because it not only fails silently, it doesn't think it's failed at all (and perhaps it hasn't, if you ask the ActiveRecord authors :).

```
valve.notes            
#=> "Level: Top"

valve.notes << "\nDirection: North"

valve.changed?         
#=> false

valve.notes_changed?   
#=> false

valve.save
#=> true

valve.reload.notes
#=> "Level: Top"
```

*You can read more about this on [Rails' API Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changes).*

#### Solution

To get around this you need to do one of two things:

1. **Let ActiveRecord know that the `notes` attribute has changed (i.e. it is now *dirty*):**

   ```
   valve.notes << "\nDirection: North"

   valve.changed?                      
   #=> false

   valve.notes_will_change!

   valve.changed?                      
   #=> true
   ```
2. **Don't use `concat()` or `<<` to append to your attributes:**

   ```
   valve.notes = "#{valve.notes}\nDirection: North"

   valve.changed?                      
   #=> true
   ```

Hope that helps at least one other soul.

JP