# Rails not saving modified attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, markdown, yaml-front-matter

I am writing a markdown blog and I want to use front matter to define meta data such as post titles. This front matter is part of the markdown field and is parsed in the controller's create action.
The issue I am facing is that my controller refuses to save the modified attributes. I have tried moving this into a  model method with before_actions which didn't work. I've also [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583596/activerecord-not-saving-after-updating-attribute) and tried the `attribute_will_change!` method in my model without success.
I am out of ideas so any help would be appreciated.

- For some reason, the `public` attribute *is* saved as expected but the rest is not.
- made sure that the fm variable contains values (works flawlessly)
- tried moving this into a model before_save action
- I've also tried removing the `||=` and replacing them with regular `=` assignment.

**Post  Controller Create**

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.public = true
    @post.user = User.first
    @post.word_count = @post.markdown.scan(/[\w-]+/).size
    fm, content = YAML::FrontMatter.extract(@post.markdown)

    @post.title_will_change!
    @post.title ||= fm[:title].to_s
    @post.subtitle ||= fm[:subtitle]
    @post.abstract ||= fm[:abstract]
    @post.video_token ||= fm[:video_token]
    @post.slug ||= fm[:slug]
    @post.seo_keywords = fm[:seo_keywords]

    if @post.image
        @post.image_id = fm[:image]
    end

    cat = Category.find_by_name(fm[:category])
    if cat.present?
        @post.category = cat
    else
        @post.category = Category.create(name: fm[:category])
    end

    new_markdown = @post.markdown.gsub(/(---\n(?:.*: '.*'\n)*---)/, '')
    @post.markdown = new_markdown
    respond_to do |format|
        if @post.save
            format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, locataion: @post }
        else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I accessed the `fm` variable with a symbol and not a string... That was the issue. Very annoying.